# Applying boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I wish to solve $u_{tt} = u_{xx}, \; 0 < x < 1$ with the initial boundary conditions $u_x(0,t) = 0$, $(0 < t< \infty)$, $u_x(1,t) = 0$ and $u(x,0) = 0$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $u_t(x,0) = \cos(\pi x) + \cos(3\pi x)$.

So we assume $u(x,y) = X(x)T(t)$ and then get $u_x = X' T$, $u_{xx} = X''T$. Similarly, $u_t = X T'$ and $u_{tt} = X T''$.

So $\frac{X''}{X} = \frac{T''}{T} = \gamma$ for some constant $\gamma$. Now I form two ODEs $T'' - \gamma T = 0$ and $X'' - \gamma X = 0$. In solving the second ODE, the char. eq. is $\lambda^2 = \gamma$. Hence, $X(x) = Ax + B$, $(\gamma = 0)$, two real equal roots. And $X(x) = Ae^{\sqrt{\gamma}x} + Be^{-\sqrt{\gamma}x}$, $(\gamma > 0)$, real but unequal roots. And $X(x) = \cos(\sqrt{-\gamma}x) + B\sin(\sqrt{-\gamma}x)$, $(\gamma < 0)$, complex roots. Here $A,B$ are constants.

Now I want to solve for the constants $A,B$ by applying the boundary conditions. But how exactly is where I am stuck. Can anyone please assist with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the facts that
\begin{align}
u_x(0, t) =& X'(0)T(t)=0 \ \ \implies \ \ \ X'(0) =0,\\
u_x(1, t) =& X'(1)T(t)= 0 \ \ \implies \ \ \ X'(1) =0
\end{align}
otherwise, your answer will be trivial. Use this to get constraints on $\gamma$.

**Spoiler Hint:**

> $\gamma=-n^2\pi^2$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ which implies $X(x)=A\cos(\pi n x)$

**Finally Hint:**

> Since $T(t)= A\cos(n\pi t)+B\sin(n\pi t)$ and $T(0) = 0$, then $T(t) = B\sin(n\pi t)$.

Comment: What you said is valid I think, but I am not sure how we use that information. From the second pair of conditions, I have $u(x,0) = X(x)T(0) = 0$ and $u_t(x,0) = X(x)T'(0) = \cos(\pi x) + \cos(3 \pi x)$. So I am not sure how I would apply what you suggested

Comment: First, ignore the second pair of conditions and see where you can use the first set of conditions.

Comment: I've applied the first set of boundary conditions to find: For gamma = 0 & gamma >0, A = B, For gamma < 0: A = B = 0. Now, I am a little confused on how to apply this to the second set of boundary conditions. I have u(x, 0) = X(x) T(0) = 0 & u_t(x,0) = X(x)T'(0) = cos(pi x) + cos(3 pi  x). When I write what T(t) is, do I use the same coefficients A,B since X(x) and T(t) are exactly the same aside for the independent var?

Comment: Apologies, for $\gamma = 0$, $A = 0$ and $B$ can vary.

Comment: In the case $\gamma<0$. You should get more than just $\gamma<0$.

Comment: You're right. Instead of obtaining the trivial case, I let $A \neq 0$ in $-A \sin(\sqrt{-\gamma}) = 0$. So, I consider $\sin(\sqrt{-\gamma}) = 0$ which has solutions when $\sqrt{-\gamma} = n \pi \implies \gamma = -n^2 \pi^2$. Then I arrive at $X(x) = A \cos(\pi n x)$ like you wrote in your edit. (Did you mean $X(x)$ instead of $X(t)$? )

Comment: @Ozera  I made the correction.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
It's interesting to start from the 'wave equation' *general solution*

> $\ds{\mrm{u}\pars{x,t} = \mrm{f}\pars{x + t} + \mrm{g}\pars{x - t}.\qquad
> \require{cancel}
> \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
> \ds{\mrm{u}\pars{x,0}} & \ds{=} & \ds{0}
> \\[1mm]
> \ds{\mrm{u}_{t}\pars{x,0}} &\ds{=} &
> \ds{\cos\pars{\pi x} + \cos\pars{3\pi x}}
> \end{array}\right.}$

$$
\bbx{\mbox{The boundary condition}\
\mrm{u}_{x}\pars{0,t} =\mrm{u}_{x}\pars{1,t} = 0\ \mbox{is}\
\color{red}{\textsf{redundant}}.}
$$

---

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcccl}
\ds{0} & \ds{=} & \ds{\mrm{u}\pars{x,0}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{x} + \mrm{g}\pars{x}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\cos\pars{\pi x} + \cos\pars{3\pi x}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\mrm{u}_{t}\pars{x,0}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\mrm{f}'\pars{x} - \mrm{g}'\pars{x}}
\end{array}\right.
$$

---

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcl}
\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{x}} & \ds{+} & \ds{\mrm{g}\pars{x}} & \ds{=} & \ds{0}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{x}} & \ds{-} & \ds{\mrm{g}\pars{x}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{{\sin\pars{\pi x} \over \pi} + {\sin\pars{3\pi x} \over 3\pi} + a}
\end{array}\right.
$$

> where $\ds{a}$ is a *constant*.

Then,
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{x}} & \ds{=} & \ds{{1 \over 6\pi}
\bracks{3\sin\pars{\pi x} + \sin\pars{3\pi x} + 3\pi a}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\mrm{g}\pars{x}} & \ds{=} & \ds{{1 \over 6\pi}
\bracks{-3\sin\pars{\pi x} - \sin\pars{3\pi x} - 3\pi a}}
\end{array}\right.
$$

---

\begin{align}
\mrm{u}\pars{x,t} & =
{3\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{x + t}} + \sin\pars{3\pi\bracks{x + t}} -
3\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{x - t}} - \sin\pars{3\pi\bracks{x - t}}\over 6\pi}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{3\cos\pars{\pi x}\sin\pars{\pi t} + \cos\pars{3\pi x}\sin\pars{3\pi t} \over 3\pi}}
\end{align}